# What are the differences of the two polar equation of two conics $\frac{l}{r}=1+e\cos{\theta}$ and $\frac{l}{r}=1-e\cos{\theta}$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

What are the differences of the two polar equation of two conics
$$\frac{l}{r}=1+e\cos{\theta}$$ and
$$\frac{l}{r}=1-e\cos{\theta}$$

I have given two figure. What the figure represent and reason behind it. I am unable to understand. [image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\theta $ in *one sense* say anti-clockwise direction *in a single setting*, after deciding *apogee datum or perigee datum*.  That can be seen from the code of any CAS..($l,p)$ same semi-latus rectum.When $\theta =\pi/2 $ it is same, the plus for decreasing radius vector and minus sign for increasing latus-rectum.

$$ l/r = 1 - \epsilon \cos \theta ;\, l/r = 1 + \epsilon \cos \theta $$

When we notice how Kepler/Newton configured datum point of conics rotation, $\theta$ is symmetric for either direction of rotation and $\pm $ sign in front of $e =0.6 $ to determine whether $\theta$  starts respectively at apogee or perigee of planetary motion.

[image: Elliipse]

Comment: Since $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$, clockwise or counterclockwise is irrelevant.

Comment: iindeed, thanks.it should not be left iimplied